# Ruby on Rails jsonparse error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Already I have spent a lot time to resolve the issue but not getting the actual reason.
I have a issue during parsing the json, below is the my josn which i am trying to format.

ERROR: 757: unexpected token at '"{\"requestId\":\"2323423432\",\"bids\":\"[ {\\"adId\\":50000001, \\"bidNative\\":100,\\"clickPayload\\":\\"clickPayload-1\\", \\"impressionPayload\\":\\"236|458795|12345\\"}, {\\"adId\\":60000002, \\"bidNative\\":200,\\"clickPayload\\":\\"clickPayload-2\\", \\"impressionPayload\\":\\"236|458795|12345\\"}, {\\"adId\\":60000002, \\"bidNative\\":300,\\"clickPayload\\":\\"clickPayload-3\\", \\"impressionPayload\\":\\"236|458795|12345\\"}]\"}"'

actually wherever it shows 2 slashes there are actually 3, but i dont know why stack overflows editor shows like this.

Comment: `bids` array contains double-escaped values. They probably are generated by something else and then combined in this json. So these values should be unescaped before adding into array

Comment: please give more information about how this json is generated